# Close edit mode only after successful post/put/delete

Tags: javascript, web-services, kendo-grid

I have a kendo ui gridview.  When user performs edits, creates or deletes, the editor exits,  performs local updates and only then does makes a call to the server.  If the call fails, the grid now contains incorrect data.  The user edits are lost.

Is there a way to ensure that the edit mode exist only after the server responds with success?

Answer (score 0):

The url below answers my question.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/mvvm/handling-validation-errors-from-server-in-kendo-grid.aspx